# Can any binary operator be turned, through an associative operator, into another associative operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity

**Motivation:** let $\circ:X^2\to X$ be some binary operator, and let $+:X^2\to X$ be some commutative operator. Then
$$\star:X^2\to X:(x,y)\mapsto (x\circ y)+(y\circ x)$$
is commutative.

---

I was wondering if there is some similar 'trick' for constructing associative operators from an arbitrary operator $\circ$.